# Loosing access to Windows VM through RDP/Bastion soon after connecting to a Client VPN using Cisco-VPN-Client

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to use a Windows VM deployed through AVD to connect to a client VPN. And client's VPN is restricted in a way that it only allows users to access few of their internal servers but nothing else. So, I'm loosing access to VM soon after connecting to the Client VPN using Cisco-Mobile-VPN client. And it looks like VPN is restricting external connectivity to the VM. As a new user to Azure, I'm trying know if there is a possible work around to access the VM even after connecting to client restricted VPN. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below procedure to fix the issue:

1. Go to the “Network and Sharing Center”
2. Click on “Change Adapter Settings”
3. Click on your VPN entry and then “Change settings of this connection” in the ribbon.
4. Drill into IP v4 properties and to the IP Settings tab. (as the above picture shows)
5. Uncheck “Use default gateway on remote network”.

If you are still facing the issue or unable to uncheck “Use default gateway on remote network”, please check if he vpn provider can add you to a group that has a policy set for 'split tunneling' - this is done on the vpn host side.

Please refer below URL for more information :

https://serverfault.com/questions/193308/vpn-within-a-remote-desktop-session?rq=1